# morgan logging in separate js with file rotator stream for node js + express

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating a test app using node js where I need a separate logger js files for winston and morgan. I have created separate file for winston and its working fine, however I am not getting how to create same for morgan logger.

My morganLogger.js looks like

```
var morgan = require('morgan');
var accessLogDirectory = __dirname + '/accessLog';
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var fileStreamRotator = require('file-stream-rotator');

//ensure log directory exists for acccess log
fs.existsSync(accessLogDirectory) || fs.mkdirSync(accessLogDirectory)

//use custom token for date
morgan.token('date', function () {
    return new Date();
});

//create a rotating write stream 
var accessLogStream = fileStreamRotator.getStream({
   filename: accessLogDirectory + '/access-%DATE%.log',
   frequency: 'daily',
   verbose: false,
   date_format: 'YYYYMMDD'
});

morgan.stream = accessLogStream;
morgan.format = ':remote-addr - :remote-user [:date[clf]] ":method :url HTTP/:http-version" :status :res[content-length]';
module.exports = morgan;
```

And my server.js looks like this,

```
var express = require('express');
var morganLogger = require('./utility/morganLogger.js');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

app.use(morganLogger());
app.use('/', routes);
```

After running code, I get logging in debugger but the log file is not created.

Comment: having same problem got anything also what is the use of winston if you are using morgan ??

Answer (score 0):

When invoking morgan by `morgan()` you can set parameters `morgan('options')` like `stream` by passing an object like `{ stream: accessLogStream }`.

When instantiating morgan, `var morganLogger = require('./utility/morganLogger.js');`, and invoking your instantiation, `app.use(morganLogger());`, try passing the parameters like this:

```
// in morganLogger.js
morgan.format = ':remote-addr - :remote-user [:date[clf]] ":method :url HTTP/:http-version" :status :res[content-length]';
morgan.options = {
    stream: accessLogStream
};

// in server.js
app.use(morganLogger (mormorganLogger.format, morganLogger.options));

// also in morganLogger.js use path.join 
// when instantiating accessLogDirectory
var accessLogDirectory = path.join(__dirname ,'/accessLog');
```